# Ranking/ weighing search result

Tags: algorithm, search, ranking, weighted

I am trying to build an application that has a smart adaptive search engine (lets say for cars).  If I search for for 4x4 then the DB will return all the 4x4 cars I have (100 cars) - but as time goes by and I start checking out cars, liking them, commenting on them, etc the order of the search result should be the different. That means 1 month later when searching for 4x4, I should get the same result set ordered differently as per my previous interaction with the site. If I was mainly liking and commenting on German cars, BMW should be on the top and Land cruiser should be further down.

This ranking should be based on attributes that I captureduring user interaction (eg: car origin, user age, user location, car type[4x4, coupe, hatchback], price range).  So for each car result I get, I will be weighing it based on how well it is performing on the 5 attributes above.

I intend to use the DB just as a repository and do the ranking and the thinking on the server. My question is, what kind of algorithm should I be using to weigh/rank my search result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically saying that you already have several ordering schemes:

- Keyword search result
- amount of likes for car's category
- likely others, such as popularity, some form of date, etc.

What you do then is make up a new scheme, call it *relevance*:

- relevance = W<sub>1</sub> * keyword_score + W<sub>2</sub>*likes_score + ...

and sort by relevance. Experiment with the weights W<sub>1</sub>, W<sub>2</sub>, ..., until you get something you find useful.

From my understanding search engines work on this principle. It's been long thrown around that Google has on the order of 200 different inputs into the relevance score, PageRank being just one. The beauty of this approach is that it lets you fine tune the importance of everything (even individually for every query), and it lets you add additional inputs without screwing everything up.

Comment: Thanks... I agree, only thing is I think I might need a bit more complex weighing formula... For example if one user has a searched 30 4x4 cars and 20 German cars.. It would be a bit hard to substitute these values in your formula...

Comment: @biso Ok, so you have two sets of categories: type of car (4x4, sedan, etc), and nationality (German, American, etc). Presumably type of car would be weighed higher.